# C# - Get Operating System from IP address / DNS Name

Tags: c#, .net-core, network-programming

We are writing an app that will manage servers and I need to be able to see what Operating System is running on any remote machine within the network.

We will not always have credentials to view this information, so WMI is not a solution.

All I need to know, is it running Windows, Linux, or other. And what is the version of the OS.

Currently we are getting this info from the databases on these servers. But I'd like to do this without asking a database.

Is it possible to get this information if I only have the IP address or DNS name? No credentials. A C#/.Net Core solution would be ideal. Or any protocols that would achieve this would also work, I'll convert it into C#.

**Conclusion**

So depending on what is available and what is not, here are the options brought forward.

1. If you have an admin account on the remote machine, WMI is the best approach. [Example on learn.microsoft.com here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/connecting-to-wmi-remotely-with-c-)
2. If you have access to a database like SQL, you can query SQL to return the OS information. This wil very from DB to DB and from version to version. So research is essential.
3. Using something like [nmap](https://nmap.org/) will get you the OS using port fingerprinting. This isn't always accurate and will depend on your server security and setup. Thanks to @MindSwipe and @BlackSpy
4. Using an agent to send this information is also a possibility, and would be a good approach, but this requires some overheads which can be avoided with the proper setup. Thanks @BlackSpy and @Clint

Comment: Does this help at all -> I am not sure you can get what OS is running -> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6aaf0d22-84cf-49ce-9d92-b45a207a571c/get-information-about-the-computers-of-a-network-?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: You can use HttpRequest.UserAgent class
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.useragent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequest_UserAgent

Comment: You can use something called TCP/IP Stack fingerprinting. nmap is a cli tool that can do this (great description on how [here](https://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html)). TCP/IP fingerprinting isn't perfect but it should get the job done. I haven't found any implementations of it in C# meaning you might have to wrap it in a cli call

Comment: Thanks @MindSwipe. I will look at nmap and see if I can incorporate it into my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is similar to a CMDB inventory scan, and there are different strategies for windows and linux. For starters, decide on whether to go agent or agent-less.

If you go the agent route, then write a small .net application that exposes a port to query and provide an OS specific implementation for both. Then get you IT department to install it on everything.

Agent-less is a bit more tricky. Start by looking for ports that should be open for management functions (WinRM on Windows - though be careful here - it's turned off by default, SSH on Linux), or any services you know your IT department provision by default (hopefully on their base VM images). If WinRM/SSH is enabled, and you have password store you can programatically query, then you can perform remote logins and run any code you need to extract any further information. As you say you don't have the passwords, the best you can do is guess based on exposed ports.

Comment: Thanks @BlackSpy, with the research I've done, I've come to the same conclusions. We're going Agent-less so this is going to be tricky.

The fingerprinting route is the most efficient in our case. But we might be doing it as a fallback. Primary will be querying the databases on these servers since this will be most accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the UserAgent string

From MSDN Doc:

> When you request a webpage, your browser sends a number of headers to
>   the server hosting the site that you're visiting, as shown here.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: microsoft.com
```

The Platform Token will describe your OS (also in the link)

You can query like this

```
 String ua = Request.UserAgent;  
 if (ua.Contains("Windows NT 10"))
     return "Windows 10";
 else if (ua.Contains("Linux"))
     return "Linux"
```

Link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/ms537503(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

OR

```
Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
```

Comment: This requires the server to make an HTTP request to your application, kinda defeating the point. Because if you need to install a program on the server you might as well install a program on it that sends the exact OS info

Comment: No you do not need a custom app to be running on the server, you are just utilizing the information that is already coming in with the header.
Moreover, we can use Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString(); as well and parse the info we need

Comment: As @MindSwipe says, this is the wrong way around. My Application needs to ask the remote machine what OS it is using. The remote machine will not be sending requests to my app.

Comment: Ahh ok my bad, do you have admin access or access to read remote registry ?

Comment: @Clint, let's assume I do not. I cannot rely on WMI.